# Pythonのnp.matrixの全要素に対する操作

Tags: python, numpy

np.matrixの全ての要素に対して(-1/2)乗したいのですが、簡単な方法はありますか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy.matrix](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) のページには「no longer recommended」とあります。使わないほうがよいでしょう。

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

---

(とりあえず `numpy.matrix` 使うとして)
`numpy.matrix` での `**` 演算子は matrix power ということなので, (`matrix` ではなく) 普通に [numpy.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) 使えばできそうです。

```py
mat = np.matrix('1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8')
arr = np.array(mat)
print(np.matrix(arr **(-1/2)))
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます